# my sql order by with values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a list of products which have an ID column as primary key, and category id which is a foreign key.. I want to overthem by a certain way.

```
ID    |   Name   | CategoryID
----------------------------
1     | one      | 1
2     | two      | 2
3     | three    | 1
4     | four     | 3
5     | five     | 5 
6     | six      | 4
7     | seven    | 2
8     | eight    | 1
```

if the above is my table. I want to get them in an SQL like the folowing

if want order these products in a certain way where all the products of category 5 needs to be 
appearing first I am running a query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM Product ORDER BY CategoryID IN (5), ID
```

this does the job well.

but now i am in need to show the category id 5 first and then category id 2 first and the rest

if I try

```
SELECT * FROM Product ORDER BY CategoryID IN (5), CategoryID IN (2), ID ASC
```

that doesnt work.

any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function:

```
SELECT * FROM Product ORDER BY FIELD(CategoryID, 2, 5) DESC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49750/1/0).

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
SELECT * FROM Product 
ORDER BY
case CategoryID
  when  5 then 0
  when  2 then 1
  else 2
end
, ID
```